# grabbing ID from Menu Item in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a database which looks like this:

```
"menu" : {
    "-KHHPThEH3NLJWJAsKAx" : {
      "itemDescription" : "Pizza Description 1",
      "itemName" : "Pizza 1",
      "itemPrice" : "$5.49"
    },
    "-KHHPZOeNirE8cTQ7qU5" : {
      "itemDescription" : "Pizza Description 2",
      "itemName" : "Pizza 2",
      "itemPrice" : "$6.85"
    },
    "-KHHPfJlC580TQ-ZKkwm" : {
      "itemDescription" : "Pizza Description 3",
      "itemName" : "Pizza 3",
      "itemPrice" : "$7.89"
    },
    "-KI5ysdg1X3EX3pHwZWQ" : {
      "itemDescription" : "Asdasdad",
      "itemName" : "example item",
      "itemPrice" : "Test"
    },
    "-KI5yzYx02ixlLi9Wt8q" : {
      "itemDescription" : "AsidfubsaoufdybsafAsdfosahpfdisaoudfhasfduasifasoudfysabfusafbasdfuaskbfasdufkbshafasdf",
      "itemName" : "™¡£¢¢∞asdfa<<>>;;;ih078t9",
      "itemPrice" : "9929130u31nsadfjnaslfdhb"
    }
  },
```

Currently I'm running a firebase query which takes each menu item as a data snapshot and extracts the menu names, descriptions, and prices and places them in some arrays for display in a table.

```
let menuItems = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/menu")
    menuItems.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        //each time we reload this data, we have to clear itemNames, otherwise it adds duplicate items.
        self.itemNames = [String]()
        self.itemPrices = [String]()
        self.itemDescriptions = [String]()

        for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {

            let name = id.value["itemName"] as! String
            self.itemNames.append(name)

            let price = id.value["itemPrice"] as! String
            self.itemPrices.append(price)

            let description = id.value["itemDescription"] as! String
            self.itemDescriptions.append(description)

        }

        print(self.itemNames)
        print(self.itemPrices)
        print(self.itemDescriptions)
        print(self.itemIDs)

        //Make sure to reload data, or else these arrays end up blank
        self.menuTable.reloadData()

    })//End get menu info
```

Now, how could I also create an array of the IDs generated for each item?  I'll admit that I'm using a copied query from another firebase question, so I'm not entirely how my initial query is working in the first place.  After some tinkering I still can't quite get there.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the ID as in the object "id" like in "id.value" or do you want those Strings of ID's like "KHHPThEH3NLJWJAsKAx"

Comment: I'm looking for strings of the ids.  This is all to enable the database to erase entire menu items when the user chooses to do so in the app.